# Why this exponent got calculated in this way at this example?

Tags: algorithm, binary, floating-point, ieee-754, discrete-mathematics

Number: 0.1101112 × 2^–3 (the first bit is included in this example in the mantissa)

where 8 bits are used for the characteristic, and the exponent bias is
2^7 – 1

Their solution:

The sign bit is 0. The characteristic is –3 + 2^7 – 1, represented as an 8-
bit binary number. The simplest way to calculate the characteristic
here is to find the 7-bit 2’s complement of the binary representation
of 4 (= 3 + 1), and adjoin a leading zero:

Binary representation of 4: 0000100
2’s complement: 1111100
Characteristic: 0111 1100

Why: my solution was get the 8-bit instead of the 7-bit complement
1111 1100 then add it to 128 8-bit representation 1000 0000

Which get me 1 0111 1100 then ignoring the ninth column I got the same answer, 
but i did not get the approach of the author.

Your explanation is highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind the original approach is to rewrite the expression

```
–3 + 2^7 – 1
```

as

```
2^7 - 4
```

The lower seven bits of this expression are the 7-bit two's complement of 4 (i.e. the representation of -4 in 7 bits). Since the number is obviously in the range 0-127, then eighth bit must be zero.

Comment: I am not quit sure i got this shortcut, is there any general rule or guideline you followed?

Comment: @skystar7No general rule or guideline, just common sense. What part exactly do you have trouble with?

Comment: It is just not that clear to me, how did you see the lower seven bits of this expression? did you compute it first?